# Banker's rounding formula in Excel

Tags: .net, excel

It is a well known problem that by default, .NET uses Banker's rounding whereby `X.5` is rounded to nearest even number. Excel, on the other hand uses arithmetic rounding where `X.5` is always rounded up, just like most of us have been taught at school.

Is it possible to perform banker's rounding in Excel using a formula?

Comment: this isn't very helpful is it ? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/194983/prb-round-function-different-in-vba-6-and-excel-spreadsheet

Comment: Are you looking for something that is expandable, as in you can vary to what decimal place it is rounded, or only worried about rounding to the integer?  If it is the first, vba will be the best method.

Comment: @Tsar what we learn at high school isn't what's actually used in statistics, signal processing, finance and engineering. Check [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) - 6 ways, 2 of them behave like banker's rounding and reduce the average error. You should pick the rounding that's appropriate for the work at hand.

Comment: @Panagiotis_Kanavos Which 2?  Which is the other beside Half toward Even? https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Round_to_even

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISEVEN(A1*10^0),MOD(A1*10^0,1)<=0.5),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),ROUND(A1,0))
```

Replace all the `0`, there are 4 of them, with the significance of the desired rounding.

Or you can create a user defined function to use VBA Round, which is Banker's Rounding:

```
Function BankerRound(rng As Double, sig As Integer) As Double

    BankerRound = Round(rng, sig)
End Function
```

Then it would simply be:

```
=BankerRound(A1,0)
```

Comment: Note that this formula can round numbers of opposite sign differently. If you want rounded opposite numbers to also be opposite, you may want to instead do:  =IF(A1>0, IF(AND(ISEVEN(A1*10^0),MOD(A1*10^0,1)<=0.5),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),ROUND(A1,0)), IF(AND(ISEVEN(A1*10^0),MOD(-A1*10^0,1)<=0.5),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),ROUND(A1,0)) )

Comment: in Excel 2010, I'm not sure that `Round` uses banker's rounding. For example `72.765` still rounds to `72.77` and not `72.76`.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(AND(ISEVEN(A1*10^0),MOD(A1*10^0,1)<=0.5),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),ROUND(A1,0))
```

I used this formula and it worked great, but in some cases, it was not working because the 0.5 actually was 0.5000000000000000004550000000000000000.

The fix is to ROUND the MOD statement to two(2) decimal places so that the computation reads:

```
=IF(AND(ISEVEN(A1*10^0),ROUND(MOD(A1*10^0,1),2)<=0.5),ROUNDDOWN(A1,0),ROUND(A1,0))
```

Comment: FWIW, for dollar amounts, I came up with `=IF(AND(ISEVEN(ROUNDDOWN(A1*100,1)),ROUNDDOWN(A1*100,1)>=A1*100),ROUNDDOWN(A1,2),ROUND(A1,2))`

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason the other codes don't work.  This is a brute force variant of the ISEVEN types of formulas.

```
    =IF(AND(RIGHT(B29,1)="5", OR((RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="0", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="2", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="4", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="6", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="8")), ROUNDDOWN(B29,2), IF(AND(RIGHT(B29,1)="5", OR((RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="1", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="3", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="5", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="7", (RIGHT(LEFT(B29,LEN(B29)-1),1))="9")),ROUNDUP(B29,2), ROUND(B29,2)))
```