# How to round a number

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have logic provided from excel as

```
CONCATENATE(ROUND(slno/256,0),ROUNDUP(((slno /256)-ROUND(slno/256,0))*256,0))
```

and i am converting in to c# the same.As per the logic if slno is `2696709` then answer should be `105345`.But when i used following c# code i am getting it as `10534-2686169`,how to correct and get it as `105345`
Wrong code i used is as below

```
decimal slno = 2696709;
string result = Math.Round((slno / 256), 0).ToString() + 
                Math.Ceiling(((slno / 256) - 
                Math.Round((slno / 256), 0) * 256)).ToString();
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could update your question to show at least 16 sample inputs and the expected results for each of those inputs.

Comment: Please be aware that Excel and `Math.Round` by default use different rounding - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310679/bankers-rounding-function-in-excel . You likely want to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_MidpointRounding_ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to order of operations. Your multiplication by 256 is taking place before your subtraction.

In this portion of your code:

```
Math.Ceiling(((slno / 256) - Math.Round((slno / 256), 0) * 256))
```

You want to make the subtraction occur first, which you can do with parenthesis.

```
Math.Ceiling((((slno / 256) - Math.Round((slno / 256), 0)) * 256))
```

*I would also look into setting an explicit [MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.7.2) value on your rounding calls, as the default (to nearest even) is often not what you are expecting over away from zero.*
*As an example, `=ROUND(2.5,0)` results in a cell with the value `3`, `Math.Round(2.5, 0)` results in `2`.*

The complete translation of the excel formula could look like this:

```
decimal slno = 2696709; 
var val = slno / 256;
var valRound = Math.Round(val, 0, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero);
var result = valRound.ToString() + Math.Ceiling((val - valRound) * 256).ToString();
```

Comment: champion:):):):)

Answer (score 2):

I did a straight substitution of your formula...

- CONCATENATE => String.Concat
- ROUND => Math.Round
- ROUNDUP => Math.Ceiling

Also, I switched to using using `AwayFromZero` [MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.7.2) as I beleive it is the Excel default, whereas .NET defaults to `ToEven`.

```
decimal slno = 2696709;
string result = String.Concat(
        Math.Round(slno/256,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero),
        Math.Ceiling(((slno /256)-Math.Round(slno/256,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))*256)
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats the answer:

```
double slno = 2696709;
var result = Math.Round(slno / 256, 0).ToString() + Math.Ceiling(((slno / 256) - Math.Round(slno / 256, 0)) * 256).ToString();
```

Comment: I didn't notice that this formula is using two functions. I fixed it. Thanks @Jonathon Chase