# Is there an easy way to get numbers to round to whatever is the even number?

Tags: excel, numbers, rounding

I work in a lab and our rounding is...different. If the number used to round is a 5 it goes toward the even number. So if we have 3.5 it rounds to a 4 and if we have 2.5 it rounds to a 2. Likewise if the number is 2.599999999, it would still round to a 2 because we are ignoring everything after the 5. I've been reading about ceiling and floors and I don't think that's quite right for what I want it to do. For the most part our excel sheets calculate things correctly but it does go haywire every so often. Was just curious if there was an easy way to get it to round the way we are rounding.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have **5**, how should it round?

Comment: This is called banker's rounding.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310679/bankers-rounding-formula-in-excel for a close but not exact dup.

Comment: @ScottCraner: Banker's rounding wouldn't round `2.599999999` to `2`, though ...

Comment: @mark but it will if you pass floor(2.599999999,1) into the udf.

Comment: @ScottCraner Oh nice! I wasn't aware it had another name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(A1),ROUND(TRUNC(A1,1)-0.01,0),ROUND(A1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this formulae.

```
=IF(MOD(FLOOR(A1,1),2)=0,FLOOR(A1,1),CEILING(A1,1))
```

It does not work with whole numbers though, but you could adjust the `FLOOR` or `CEILING` to achieve it.